# Linux On A Mp3Player

Tags: mp3

there is a way to install Linux/A *libre* OS in to a mp3 player ?
I'm only curious, so i don't want to now that for a specific device but in general

Comment: I actually think you will have to say something about the device you are targeting, as any computer is an MP3 player.

Comment: In general this question makes very little sense. An imaginary MP3 player may be 1) locked down 2) don't have enough RAM/ROM to run Linux 3) not have any writable ROM etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.